# Why didn't Vegeta get revived by Yamcha's wish?

Tags: dragon-ball, dragon-ball-z

In **[episode 240 of Dragon Ball Z](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Revival)** ([episode 123 of Dragon Ball Kai](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Found!_A_Faint_Ray_of_Hope!_Awaken,_Warriors!)), Bulma gathers the Dragon Balls and calls Shenron. She wants to revive the people that Majin Vegeta killed in the World Martial Arts Tournament Stadium.

She doesn't know how to phrase the wish and **Yamcha** does it for her:

> "Bring back to life everyone that died today! Er, except the bad guys!"

[image: yamcha making wish 1]

[image: yamcha making wish 2]

Vegeta is not revived, even though he sacrificed himself, proving that he has good in him.

Didn't he get revived because he is still considered a bad guy by Shenron?

Comment: Vegeta *was* bad.

Answer (score 1):

As far as it is shown in the Manga and Anime, Shenron can only bring people back to life once.

That's why Goku was so mad when Frieza killed Krillin, since even though Piccolo and Kami were alive, he wouldn't be able to bring him back. Vegeta was revived once with the wish from Mr. Popo to bring back everyone killed by Frieza and his men. This didn't revive Krillin, since he had died and come back before.

During the Buu Saga, after Vegeta died and Yamcha wished for everyone who died that day to be brought back, except for the bad guys. The wish would have affected Vegeta as he was judged good enough by King Yemma to keep his body and later by Porunga to be revived (though Dende did specify "really really evil" instead of just "bad" like Yamcha), but didn't as he had already been brought back. What is interesting is that Yamcha's wish after the Cell Saga didn't bring back King Kai or Bubbles as they have not been shown to have died and been wished back before.

Vegeta is finally revived by Porunga on New Namek when Dende wishes for everyone who had died to come back except for the really really evil ones. If Dende had somehow got around the one revival limitation during the 7 year gap between the end of the Cell Saga and the start of the Buu Saga, then it may be due to Shenron considering Vegeta a "bad guy" but Porunga not considering him "really really evil".